# Google App Engine channel code fails in production with javascript "Cannot read property 'removeEventListener' of undefined " error

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine

I have code that used to work and still works with the latest SDK 1.8.3 However in production it does not work any more. It fails right here:

```
ch = new goog.appengine.Channel(token);
ch.open();  <--- this never returns
```

The browser debugger shows the stacktrace below. The channek.js code from production https://talkgadget.google.com/talkgadget/channel.js

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeEventListener' of undefined [VM] channel.js (18280):22
Qb [VM] channel.js (18280):22
cb [VM] channel.js (18280):14
g.Ma [VM] channel.js (18280):30
Zd [VM] channel.js (18280):88
ae [VM] channel.js (18280):87
$ [VM] channel.js (18280):95
ge.open [VM] channel.js (18280):100
reset 062a630fa51c7bd829554631f0939936-school_swapp.js:1
(anonymous function)
```

In the case of the SDK I also see some random javascript stack traces that look like the one below but with the SDK the code works as expected. I mention this for completeness in case somebody can spot the issue.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'markAsRemoved' of undefined jsapi:3069
goog.events.ListenerMap.removeAll jsapi:3069
goog.events.EventTarget.removeAllListeners jsapi:3159
goog.events.EventTarget.disposeInternal jsapi:3142
goog.net.XhrIo.disposeInternal jsapi:4915
goog.Disposable.dispose jsapi:2538
goog.net.XhrIo.cleanupSend_ jsapi:4841
goog.events.EventTarget.fireListeners jsapi:3171
goog.events.EventTarget.dispatchEventInternal_ jsapi:3207
goog.events.EventTarget.dispatchEvent jsapi:3138
goog.net.XhrIo.cleanUpXhr_ jsapi:4955
goog.net.XhrIo.onReadyStateChangeHelper_ jsapi:4943
goog.net.XhrIo.onReadyStateChangeEntryPoint_ jsapi:4927
goog.net.XhrIo.onReadyStateChange_
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got to the bottom of this. If you add any method like the one below somewhere in your javascript

```
Object.prototype.foobar = function() {}
```

then the problem I described in my question happens!!! Removing/changing such code resolved the issue. Sounds like a bug in production channel.js code to me.

Answer (score 0):

My channel API is working fine.

I think I've seen other comments on SO about channels created with version X of an app not working with channels created with version Y, is that what you're running into?

Comment: I tie the channel to the session so even when there is an update of the code, when the user logs out/in again the new channel should work fine.